# My looping code in prolog won't work with the rest of my code

Tags: recursion, prolog

I am working on a school assignment where I have to find the smallest hitting set of a list of lists. Right now I am working on finding all the hitting sets before I narrow it down to the smallest one. I implemented a way for my code to find out if two lists have at least one number in common. To my knowledge it works as intended by itself but whenever I try to connect it to the main part of my code it won't work or runs indefinitely. Any help would be appreciated.

Minimal, Reproducible Example:

This code has been made in a way that it will return true anytime a two arrays have at least one number that intersects between the two. I have tested this code and to my knowledge it works as intended. The first result back is always correct when I tested it.

```
checkForIntersection([],[]):- false.
checkForIntersection([Head|Tail],[Head2|Tail2]):-
  Head = Head2;
  checkForIntersection(Tail,[Head2|Tail2]);
  checkForIntersection([Head|Tail],Tail2).
```

This part of the code is where I believe an error occurs. I have an AnswerSet as the list that I want to check for intersections. The [Check|NextCheck] is a list of lists and I want to check each of them against the AnswerSet. I loop through it until the [Check|NextCheck] is empty. The issue is that when I call it the results I get is an infinite amount of trues even if the answer should be false.

```
loopThroughListOfLists(CheckListsAgenstThisList,[]).
loopThroughListOfLists(CheckListsAgenstThisList,[ListToCheck|NextListToCheck]):-
   checkForIntersection(ListToCheck,CheckListsAgenstThisList),
   loopThroughListOfLists(CheckListsAgenstThisList,NextListToCheck).
```

loopCheck([3],[[1], [1], [3], [4], [4]]). This is one of the cases I used to test my code with. Instead of returning false it returns an infinite amount of trues whenever I test it.

Thank you so much for reading, I am sorry if this is a really stupid question, I am really struggling with Prolog.

Comment: You need to produce a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise you let us guess too much.

Comment: @false AH, got it. I will edit it with more information and an example. Sorry.

Comment: @false I hope this is better. Thank you for taking the time to let me know about this :)

Comment: Which query unexpectedly fails/succeeds?

Comment: @false Whenever I call loopCheck([3],[[1], [1], [3], [4], [4]]). it succeeds when it should fail. 3 is not in [1] ,[1],[4],[4]. [3] is in [3] but since it is checking each of them it should fail since not all of them return true. The return it gives me is true to infinity but it should be simply false.

Comment: This example does not look minimal to me, you certainly can reduce it. After all, you do not state the intended meaning of your programs. loopcheck does not say much.

Comment: @false Sorry, I changed the variables to be more simple. Thank you for that though. I found a spelling error that was causing my code to not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209225/discussion-between-jack-van-well-and-false).

Comment: `I am sorry if this is a really stupid question` It is not a stupid question. @false is one of the best Prolog programmers in the world, but sometimes I don't know where he is going. You are doing fine, don't worry.

Comment: @GuyCoder: OP undid my formatting changes for `(;)/2`. EOD

Comment: @false , Sorry I was editting my code to make it a minimal verifiable example. I thought that the website was auto formatting it so I kept changing it. I also am sorry about the chat thing. I didn't mean to click on it.